# Как вывести картинку из генератора keras через matplotlib?

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, keras

Я обучил нейронную сеть с помощью keras, вот ее код:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, GlobalAveragePooling2D, Dropout
import random
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    "C:/python/nn/cats_vs_dogs/train",
    target_size=(224, 224),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='binary')

test_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    "C:/python/nn/cats_vs_dogs/test",
    target_size=(224, 224),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='binary')

base_layers = keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=(224, 224, 3), include_top=False)
base_layers.trainable = False

model = keras.Sequential([
                             base_layers,
                             GlobalAveragePooling2D(),
                             Dropout(0.2),
                             Dense(1)
])

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001), metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_generator, epochs=2, batch_size=32)

model.evaluate(test_generator)
```

После этого мне бы хотелось вывести пару картинок из тестовой выборки. Я попробовал сделать это так:

```
plt.imshow(test_generator[0])
```

На что получил ошибку:

> could not broadcast input array from shape (32,224,224,3) into shape (32).

Мне кажется, что она вызвана разделением на батчи.

Как правильно вывести картинку из тестовой выборки?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
plt.imshow(test_generator.next()[0])
```

Comment: Invalid shape (32, 224, 224, 3) for image data

Comment: @ILEM, вы запустили код из ответа без изменений?

Comment: да, именно так я и сделал